# How to change upper half of screen to list view when user types input (dictionary app)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm writing a dictionary app. My search screen is very simple: centered in the `Activity` is the app's logo, and aligned to the bottom of the screen is the search box. When the search box receives focus, the soft keyboard pops up and the search box moves right on top of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/search_logo"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_transparent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_logo"
        />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/search_fld"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As soon as the user types even a single letter, I will make a query in Lucene for matching entries. I want the view on top of the search box to be a dynamically updating `ListView` for every letter that is typed (or deleted), but how can I do that from this XML layout? What is the right approach to this kind of design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be more straightforward. First, create a `TextWatcher` for the `EditText`. Then, inside `onTextChanged()`, this is what you do:

1. Create a Lucene query whenever the method is invoked. Get the results.
2. Call `clear()` in the adapter.
3. Add all the results to the adapter.
4. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Answer (score 3):

Following are the pointers which will eventually guide you to your answer.

1. Add a `textwatcher` to the editfield in which you are going to write the search words..

   ```
    txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
   ```
2. In `afterTextChanged` method of textwatcher you will need a filter with the characters typed in searchfield as parameter, to filter out the search result.

   ```
   private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
           int count) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
           int after) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

       adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
   }
   };
   ```
3. Following is a class I used for filtering purpose.

   ```
   /*
    * Class that implements filtering functionality.
    */
   public class MyFilter extends Filter {
       public MyFilter(ArrayList<CustomerListRow> data) {
       }

       @Override
       protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

           constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
           FilterResults result = new FilterResults();

           if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
               ArrayList<CustomerListRow> filt = new ArrayList<CustomerListRow>();

               for (int i = 0; i < arrayListCopy.size(); i++) {
                   CustomerListRow each = arrayListCopy.get(i);
                   if (each.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                       filt.add(each);
                   }
               }
               result.count = filt.size();
               result.values = filt;
           } else {
               synchronized (this) {
                   result.count = arrayListCopy.size();
                   result.values = arrayListCopy;
               }
           }

           return result;
       }

       @Override
       protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
               FilterResults results) {
           ArrayList<CustomerListRow> filtered = (ArrayList<CustomerListRow>) results.values;
           clear();

           int size = filtered.size();
           for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
               add(filtered.get(i));
           }
           notifyDataSetInvalidated();
       }
   }
   ```
4. You will need to create an adapter to which you will pass your complete list, which will eventually passed to the filter. 
   Following is constructor of my adapter class.

   ```
           public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
               List<CustomerListRow> objects) {
           super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
           this.context = context;
           inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                   .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           list = (ArrayList<CustomerListRow>) objects;
           filter = new MyFilter(list);
           arrayListCopy.addAll(list);
       }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to be what I need. I think your code assumes that I already have all of my dictionary entries in a single `ListView`. However, it's more like as I type, I create a query in Lucene, and simply use the `ListView` as a presentation of results. Ultimately, the query searches not only the words but their description too.